# Como fazer uma regressão linear no postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, regressão

Desejo fazer uma regressão linear simples diretamente no banco de dados. Observei que o postgresql já tem algumas funções estatística, que me parece serem para este fim (`regr_slope(Y, X)`, `regr_intercept(Y, X)`, `regr_count(Y, X)`...) e gostaria compreendei isso melhor.

Numa regressão simples `Y=aX+b`, `regr_intercept(Y, X)` seria igual a "b" e `regr_slope(Y, X)` igual a "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. O comando `regr_intercept(Y, X)` retorna o intercepto, isto é, o valor `b` da equação `Y=aX+b`, e o comando `regr_slope(Y, X)` retorna o coeficiente angular, também chamado de inclinação da retar.